# entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty returns null

Tags: breeze

```
  return datacontext.fetchEntity('Hearing', vm.hearingID()).then(function (result) {
            vm.hearingEntity = result.entity;
            vm.hearingEntity.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty("Client");
        });
```

What can be the reason behind "Client" navigation property returned as null in the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"loadNavigationProperty" is an asynchronous method that returns a promise. You need to wait for the promise to return. Something like:

```
 vm.hearingEntity.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty("Client").then(function(data) {
   // this is your result.
   var clients = data.results;
 });
```